# Difficulty compiling my project with error being thrown on gatsby-source-contentful

Tags: environment-variables, gatsby, access-token, contentful, gatsby-plugin

I'm currently experiencing the following error when running `gatsby develop`.

```
Error: Cannot access Contentful space "*********6qi" on environment "master with access token "************************************

  *********kWLc". Make sure to double check them! (value)

  - gatsby-node.js:51
    [portfolio]/[gatsby-source-contentful]/gatsby-node.js:51:13

  - task_queues:94 processTicksAndRejections
    node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5

  - gatsby-node.js:43 validateContentfulAccess
    [portfolio]/[gatsby-source-contentful]/gatsby-node.js:43:3

  - validator.js:82 Object.exports.entryAsync
    [portfolio]/[joi]/lib/validator.js:82:32


not finished load plugins - 21.846s
```

My `.env.development` file is up and working and I have tried using string literals in `gastby-config.js` as well as using ticks around my Space ID and Access Token as well as no ticks and no string literals.  I have also hardcoded these values into `gatsby-config.js` and this has not worked either.

This is what `gatsby-source-contentful` looks like:

```
{
           resolve: `gatsby-source-contentful`,
            options: {
                spaceId: `${process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID}`,
                accessToken: `${process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
            },
        },
```

At this point, my question is more along the lines of could this be an issue with my code someplace else, and has anyone experienced anything similar?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you added the `require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})` ?

Comment: Can you hardcode your space id/access token in gatsby-config and see if that works? Then you can be sure that the configuration is working.

Comment: *I have also hardcoded these values into gatsby-config.js and this has not worked either.*

Comment: @FerranBuireu ```require('dotenv').config({
    path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
});``` is in my `gatsby-config.js` file.  Thanks.

Comment: @stefanjudis I have tried hardcoding my space id and access token in `gatsby-config.js` and this has returned the same error that is posted above, thanks.

Comment: Just to be sure... have you copied correctly the tokens? Because if even hardcoding worked... (check the empty spaces in the end, etc)

Comment: @FerranBuireu Yes, I have double-checked my credentials (hard-coding has not worked).  I'm wondering if I should try to eliminate some possibilities with a minimum reproducible case.  I could try a fresh gatsby-new project. Only install the contentful package and try out my credentials.  I believe that if that were to work, my code would be the problem.  If that doesn't work, the problem is my system.  Is that correct?

Comment: @FerranBuireu If hard coding didn't work then something in your configuration is not correct. Some ideas to check? Are your credentials for the correct space? Do the credentials have access to the master environment? Do you use the correct token (Content Delivery or Content Preview token)?

Comment: Additionally, you could try a plain curl as described in the docs to really be sure the tokens work. https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-delivery-api/#/reference/entries/entries-collection/get-all-entries-of-a-space/console/curl

Comment: Yes, try to create a new fresh install or a new SandBox

Comment: @FerranBuireu I was finally able to try this out with a `gatsby new` project and the same credentials.  This threw the following error: 


`Error: Cannot access Contentful space "************" on environment "master with access token "************************************
  *************". Make sure to double check them! (value)`

I'm assuming that this would indicate that there is a problem with my system, is that correct?  

Thanks.

Comment: Well, to me, this leads to double-check the Contentful environment, that the CMS has everything properly set and the credentials correctly copied. Try creating a new environment with new API tokens and change them locally too.

Answer (score 0):

I found the exact problem as yours. I will show how I solve this problem step by step:
**-Step 1:** Create a `.env` file in the root directory. and paste this line `CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN = YOUR API KEYS`
**-Step 2:** Open `gatsby-config.js` and paste `require("dotenv").config()` 
then paste this line into your plugins array (Don't forget to change spaceID)

```
{
      resolve: `gatsby-source-contentful`,
      options: {
        spaceId: "your space ID",
        environment: "development",
        accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
      },
    },
```

if this process doesn't work create a new environment in contentful
[contentful add new environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdTlQ.png)